# Плавная прокрутка к якорю в табах

Tags: javascript

Есть два меню и два открывающихся таба, необходимо при клике на одно из меню прокрутить плавно к якорю который находится НАД меню табами.

Пример HTML кода:

```html
*ЗДЕСЬ ЯКОРЬ ДЛЯ МЕНЮ 1 И МЕНЮ 2*
<nav> 
  <ul>
    <li class="tab-current">
      <a href="#menu-1" class="active"><span>МЕНЮ</span>
      </a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#menu-2" class="active"><span>МЕНЮ2</span>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content-wrap"> 
<section id="menu-1">
  ЗДЕСЬ большой текст
</section>
<section id="menu-2">
ЗДЕСЬ большой текст
</section>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $( 'YOUR_DINAMIC_SELECTOR' ).offset().top // - 90
}, 500)
```

Вот код для плавной прокрутки на JQ
Если есть прилипающие меню, то уберите комментарий около "- 90". Здесь 90 - это будет высота прилипающего меню